# Wpf combobox Databinding with parent/child table

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm new to wpf and DataBinding. I tried wpf in a little application.
And now i have a problem using CollectionViewSource in combination with combobox

in a Datagrid i show the content of table "OrderDetails"
And now the problem: i would like to display the field "PartId" as Combox. the combox should contains all "Parts" and displays the "Name" not the PartId

(sorry i cant upload Picture of DB-layout)

Table **OrderDetails**:*Id*,OrderId,PartId,Count

Table **Parts**: *Id*, Name, Description, Price

```
<DataGrid Margin="80,0,0,0" Background="Transparent" HeadersVisibility="Column" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource projectsOrderdetailsViewSource}}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Fahrzeug" Width="SizeToHeader">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                     <ComboBox  DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource partsViewSource}}" 
                       SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ID}"
                       SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=PartId}"/>
                 </DataTemplate>
             </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn>
....
```

the datagrid and the containing Combobox is displayed,
but

1. the value isn't show correctly.
2. If i select anything from the combobox, all items of the datagrid gets the selected value.

Can you help me to configure the combobox correctly

Comment: What happens with the code as it is now?

Comment: the datagrid and the containing Combobox is displayed, but

the value isn't show correctly.
If i select anything from the combobox, all items of the datagrid gets the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably binding to a single partsViewSource.

partsViewSource need to be a property of projectOrderdetailsViewSource so each row has it's own partsViewSource

The list need to a public property so each row has it's own list.

```
class order
{
    public Int ID {get; private set;}
    public List<string> Parts { get; set }
}
```

Comment: thx blam. can you help me to write the Xamlcode for your answer.

Comment: thx blam. can you help me to write the Xamlcode for your answer.
current-Xaml-Code:
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="partsViewViewSource" Source="{Binding Path=Parts, Source={StaticResource database}}" />

<CollectionViewSource x:Key="projectOrderDetailsViewSource" Source="{Binding Path=xyz, Source={StaticResource xyz}}" />